# iLO Interface connections of storage device in the server rack

Tags: hp, interface, rack, network-topology

I have a setup of 3 racks. In each there are 2 storage server (HP DL560 GEN8) and 4 compute server (HP DL360 GEN8) and 2 control planes (HP DL360 GEN8) and on top of the rack 2 patch panels. Above all the 3 racks two spine switches are used to connect all of them. Please check the picture below as an example of one rack.

[Racklayout End of Row (EoR)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EowGf.png)

I am not sure if I need to make further connections, e.g. connecting storage device to compute device through an iLO (HP propriety internet port)?

Does the overall topology look ok, or do I miss something?

Any help/ feedback will be much appreciated!

Many thanks and please let me know if more info is required. Turan

Comment: iLo is not part of your existing device. It's better to think of it as a single device separate from the server. It is not a way to programmatically access the contents of the other server. Generally it should not be on your production Network as well for security reasons. This can either be done as a physical separation or logical using vlans. An iLo device is Diagnostics and remote KVM. The functionality of which depends a lot on the version and type of iLo firmware installed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your overall connectivity requirements. It depends on what you're doing.

However, the [Integrated Lights-Out](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/servers/integrated-lights-out-ilo.html) (ILO) is a management port. It is intended for out-of-band management access to the server. ILO should not be used to connect between servers.

Comment: The overall architecture follows the "spine leaf architecture". The architecture ensures that one component can always fail and that each terminal device has the shortest possible communication path to other terminals within a block.